# Automatic filing of pdf letter activity within civicase

Tags: civicase, pdf

I am experimenting with "create printable letter" from within a civicase case as a mechanism for writing a letter to that particular client. However the resulting letter does not get automatically filed as a case activity, and there is no "file on case" button on the popup. It is possible to subsequently locate the activity and then file it on case but this is time consuming.

Is there a way to have the letter automatically filed within civicase in a similar manner to which e-mails are automatically filed?

Thanks in advance.

NB We are still using civicrm 4.5.5

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Administer > CiviCase > Case Types** and add "Print PDF Letter" as an allowed activity to your case type. You will then be able to create a PDF directly from the "Manage Case" screen.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but that has already been done. The problem is that when a pdf letter is created within the case, the activity is not filed in the case. Any suggestions gratefully received

Answer (score 3):

You're right this is a bug.

I've filed issue [CRM-16596](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16596) with a PR to fix it in the next release (4.6.4).

Comment: @ColemanThat is good news - thanks for your help.